# Crystal Reports группировать данные по "плавающим" часам

Tags: sql, crystalreport

стоит такой вопрос. Существует таблица SQL с данными по расписанию поездов. В ней две колонки - `rasp_date`, которая отвечает за выезд поезда, и `race_hours`, которое указывает на время поездки этого поезда до конечного пункта. Приведу пример данной таблицы:

```
RASP_DATE                  RACE_HOURS
01.10.2020 15:05:00        4
01.10.2020 15:35:00        3
01.10.2020 16:10:00        8
01.10.2020 16:25:00        6
```

Нужно разработать отчет на основе этих данных, посчитать, какое суммарное время поездки каждый час. Например, по примеру выше отчет выдаст, что с 15:00 до 16:00 суммарное время поездки - 7 часов, с 16:00 до 17:00 - 14 часов. Данная задача легко выполняется при помощи группировки.
Однако, стоит задача немного другая - рассчитать количество часов поездки в "плавающем" часе. Пользователь вводит параметр "время минут" (например, 15), который кратен 5, и теперь "окна" должны рассчитываться не с 15:00 до 16:00, а с 15:15 до 16:15, с 17:15 до 18:15, и т.д.
Скорее всего, для этого нужно менять группировку, но точно не знаю, как это сделать. Прошу, пожалуйста, подсказать.

Comment: Во-первых, исходные данные конвертируете в вид начало-конец. Во-вторых, в отдельном подзапросе/CTE генерируете список нужных диапазонов в том же формате. А потом связываете по наложению и считаете время пересечения.

Comment: В принципе, суть алгоритма действий понятна. Однако, непонятно, как конкретно это сделать в кристале..

Comment: В кристалле - я фиг знает. Делайте на стороне SQL - кристалл должен отображать, а не считать.

Comment: Тут вопрос в том, что параметр "плавающего часа" должен вводиться пользователем именно в кристале..

Comment: И чё? ну ввёл он... всё равно после ввода надо что? данные перезапросить. Может, он предыдущим разом ввёл 7 минут, а теперь 13 - как ты из предыдущего массива данных получишь новый? да никак... А будешь перезапрашивать - передашь введённый юзером интервал как параметр.

Comment: Для простоты задачи можно взять интервалы, кратные 5 минутам (сейчас отредактирую задачу). Если создавать отдельные, например, вью в sql, а потом брать промежутки, то запросы на большие данные будут выполняться очень долго, думаю. Уверен, в кристале это делается в 3-4 строки, только вот не знаю, как именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, пришел к решению вопроса. Делается группировка по плавающему часу вот так:

1. Создать параметр "minutes".
2. Создать новую формулу "floating_hour":

   ```
   if minute({TableName.RASP_DATE}) < {?minutes} then
   time(hour({TableName.RASP_DATE})-1,{?minutes},0) else
   if minute({TableName.RASP_DATE}) >= {?minutes} then
   time(hour({TableName.RASP_DATE}),{?minutes},0)
   ```
3. Создана группа и группировка по "RASP_DATE" (По неделям)
4. Создана группа и группировка по формуле "floating_hour".
5. При помощи инструментов CR просуммировано RACE_HOURS по группе "floating_hours".

Answer (score 1):

Пример получения данных по указанному размеру окна. СУБД и версия не указана, использован MySQL версии 8. Суммарная длительность посчитана в минутах.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(start)) DIV 3600) * 3600) start,
                 TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(start)) DIV 3600) * 3600), @chunk) finish
          FROM test
        UNION ALL
          SELECT TIMESTAMP(start, @chunk), TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(start, @chunk), @chunk)
          FROM cte1
          WHERE start < ( SELECT MAX(start + INTERVAL length HOUR)
                          FROM test ) )
,
cte2 AS ( SELECT start, start + INTERVAL length HOUR finish
          FROM test )
SELECT cte1.start, 
       cte1.finish,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, GREATEST(cte1.start, cte2.start), LEAST(cte1.finish, cte2.finish))) total,
       GROUP_CONCAT(cte2.start) starts
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON cte1.start <= cte2.finish AND cte2.start <= cte1.finish
GROUP BY cte1.start, 
         cte1.finish;
```

`test` - таблица исходных данных

`@chunk` - (введённый юзером) размер окна

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fcd49441b93f90fe956574d87914370b)

Запрос дополнительно, для контроля, выводит список `start` тех записей, которые учтены в суммарном времени для текущего окна.

Если необходимо вывести данные не за весь период, а только за определённый отрезок, измените соотв. образом `cte1` и генерируйте список окон на основании требуемых границ.

Comment: Большое спасибо, но не очень понял, как работает запрос.. А еще, видимо, я не очень четко пометил, в кристале промежуток должен браться всегда ЧАС, то есть если пользователь вводит, скажем, "30", то будут браться все промежутки, с 30 минутами, скажем, 15:30, 16:30, 17:30 и т.д. А потом уже из них рассчитываться суммарные часы.

Comment: @Gipnomanul *не очень понял, как работает запрос* Выполни отдельно `cte1` и `cte2` - авось станет яснее. *если пользователь вводит, скажем, "30", то будут браться все промежутки, с 30 минутами, скажем, 15:30, 16:30, 17:30 и т.д.* Ну подкорректировать соотв. образом `cte1` - именно оно задаёт окна для подсчёта.

Comment: Хорошо, еще раз спасибо, сейчас с этим запросом поработаю. Однако, буду ждать, может, еще кто подскажет, как именно в CR это сделать.